# Paperclip - exclude zip, rar from cropping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I have an `Attachment` model, which is using `Paperclip` to handle uploaded files. The file can be anything an image, a txt, doc, pdf, rar, zip, tar etc.
I want to create thumbnails only if the file uploaded is an image.
How to create thumbnails in Paperclip conditionally based upon file content_type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a nice solution:

```
before_post_process :image?
def image?
  !(data_content_type =~ /^image.*/).nil?
end
```

You can also use the image? method in your views to either render an image_tag, or something else...